# Error related to using Qthread class in network programming

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on a project, where I have 3 pushbuttons. when the user pushes them, some informations(input number, Ip, port and pm) is read from an ini file, then the InputDetected() signal declared in my class emits and after emitting this signal, I want to make a connection with the server and send the pms to the server.
To this end, I created the buttons in the dialog class . Inside the tcpclient class, I have ConfigClass() function to read the ini file and in order to make a connection with the server and send pms to it, I Have used the InputDetected() signal which its slot is Callrun() function. Inside the Callrun function, I have started the thread() that its run function exists inside the "Mythread" class.
When I run the program, I got the error: 'tcpclient' doesn't name a type (this error is related to the mythread.h file)

I would appreciate if someone could help me fix this error . Also, I don't know if I have correctly used qthread class in order to make a connection with the server. I would be grateful if someone told me if something is wrong with the concept of my code

my code:
dialog.h:

```
  #ifndef DIALOG_H
  #define DIALOG_H

  #include <QDialog>
  #include "tcpclient.h"

  namespace Ui {
  class Dialog;
  }

   class Dialog : public QDialog
 {
   Q_OBJECT

public:
   explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
   ~Dialog();

   tcpclient myClients[3];

 private slots:
     void on_pushButton_clicked();

     void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

     void on_pushButton_3_clicked();

  private:
      Ui::Dialog *ui;
   };

  #endif // DIALOG_H
```

mythread.h:

```
#ifndef MYTHREAD_H
#define MYTHREAD_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include "tcpclient.h"

class MyThread : public QThread
 {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   explicit MyThread(QObject *parent = nullptr);

   void run();

   QTcpSocket *socket;



   tcpclient *client;


signals:

 public slots:
 };

#endif // MYTHREAD_H
```

tcpclient.h:

```
 #ifndef TCPCLIENT_H
 #define TCPCLIENT_H

 #include <QObject>
 #include <QDebug>
 #include <QSettings>
 #include <QTcpSocket>
 #include "mythread.h"

 class tcpclient : public QObject
 {
     Q_OBJECT
 public:
    explicit tcpclient(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    void ConfigClass();
    void StartClass(int _input);

    QString ip;
    QString pm;
    int port;
    int input;
    QTcpSocket *socket;
    MyThread *mthread;

 signals:
   void InputDetected();

public slots:
    void Callrun();
};

#endif // TCPCLIENT_H
```

dialog.cpp:

```
  #include "dialog.h"
  #include "ui_dialog.h"

 Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
       myClients[i].StartClass(i+1);
    }
 }

Dialog::~Dialog()
 {
    delete ui;
  }

void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
 {
     emit myClients[0].InputDetected();
  }

 void Dialog::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
  {
      emit myClients[1].InputDetected();
  }

  void Dialog::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
 {
     emit myClients[2].InputDetected();
  }
```

tcpclient.cpp:

```
 #include "tcpclient.h"
 #include "mythread.h"

tcpclient::tcpclient(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
 {

  }

void tcpclient::StartClass(int _input)
{
    input = _input;

    ConfigClass();

    connect(this,SIGNAL(InputDetected()), this, SLOT(Callrun()));


 }

void tcpclient::ConfigClass()
{
    QSettings setting(QString("config.ini"),QSettings::IniFormat);

    QString tmp = "ServerInfo" + QString::number(input);
    QString m1 = tmp + "/Ip";
    QString m2 = tmp + "/Port";
    QString m3 = tmp + "/in";
    QString m4 = tmp + "/pm";
    ip = setting.value(m1,"192.167.1.23").toString();
    port = setting.value(m2,0).toInt();
    input = setting.value(m3,0).toInt();
    pm = setting.value(m4,"hi").toString();

 }


  void tcpclient::Callrun()
 {
    mthread = new MyThread(this);
    mthread->start();
 }
```

mythread.cpp:

```
#include "mythread.h"
#include "tcpclient.h"
#include <QDebug>

 MyThread::MyThread(QObject *parent) : QThread(parent)
  {

  }


void MyThread::run()
{


   qDebug() << "class number = " << client->input;
   qDebug() << "server ip is: "<<client->ip;
   qDebug() << "server port: "<<client->port;


   socket = new QTcpSocket(this);

   socket->connectToHost(client->ip,client->port);


   if(socket->waitForConnected(3000))
   {
      qDebug() << "Connected!";


      QByteArray data = client->pm.toUtf8();
      socket->write(data);


      socket->waitForBytesWritten(1000);


      socket->waitForReadyRead(3000);


      qDebug() << "Reading"<<socket->bytesAvailable();


      qDebug() << socket->readAll();

      socket->close();
   }
  else
  {
      qDebug() << "Not connected";
   }


  }
```

Comment: Cyclic dependency, tcpclient.h includes mythread,h and mythread.h includes tcpclient.h. Break the cycle and the error will go away. You can do this with a *forward declaration* `class tcpclient;` in mythread.h.

Comment: @john Thank you for replying. I removed #include "tcpclient.h" from Mythread.h file, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you add the forward declaration as well?

Comment: @john could you please explain what do you mean by forward declaration?

Comment: In mythread,h before `class MyThread ...` add the line `class tcpclient;`. This is a forward declaration, it tells the compiler that tcpclient is a class but says nothing more about it. This is what enables you to break the cycle, because you do have to tell the compiler that tcpclient is a class, but you cannot do that by including the tcpclient.h header file because that creates the cycle of header files.

Comment: @john thank you so much. I added the forward declaration. Now my code runs, but when I push a button, it crashes. When I run the program in debug mode, it shows something is wrong inside the run function (segmentation error related to qDebugs inside the run function).

Comment: I know nothing about QT, so if you can't sort it I would ask a new question.